# warning not visible in python pdb

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, spyder

I'm using the Spyder IDE (2.2.5) with Python (2.7.6 64 bits) with Windows 7 and I'm getting a warning in numpy (v1.8.0) when I execute a set of lines in the interpreter. If however I use pdb.set_trace() and then execute the lines, I don't see the warning. Why is that?

The warning info is:

...\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:2629: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in rint

The offending line of code is:

```
sxs1 = np.round(sx*scale)
```